# PHP CRON Job within CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am attempting to create a CRON job which points to a function inside a file in a Code Igniter system I have built.
I have created the CRON job on my CPanel and I have tested it using a simple mail php function inside a file at the root and this works correctly, however, I wish to point the CRON job to a location within my MVC framework and for some reason this does not seem to be working.

Here is the CRON job set up on my CPanel:

0   0   *   *   1   wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.urlhere.co.uk/index.php/cron_event/send_reminders

and here is the controller I wish to run. The location of it is in the system/controllers/cron_event.php:

```
<?php

class Cron extends Controller {

function Cron_event()
{
    parent::Controller();
}


/**
 * The index method just displays an access denied message, as we don't support viewing this module in the browser.
 */
function index()
{
    $this->send_reminders();
    $this->load->view('themes/base/header', array('title'=>"Access Denied"));
    $this->load->view('cron/access_denied');
    $this->load->view('themes/base/footer');


}


/**
 * Updates the PR Online Calendar by sending out email notifications for events that have not yet had them sent out.
 */

public function send_reminders() {
    $to = 'jamesholman@urlgoeshere.co.uk';
    $from = 'bigwavetest';
    $message = 'test';

    mail($to, $from, $message); 
}
}

?>
```

When I point to this controller the CRON job stops working.
I have a feeling it is because I am not including and requiring the Code Igniter framework files but am unsure.
Does anybody have any ideas as to why this isn't working?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there any accesscontrol or login mechanism implemented in the application?

Comment: Ah yes I hadn't thought about that. Yes there is a login system implemented. Would this cause an issue?

Comment: You have to exclude the Cron_event controller from the login mechanism. You cannot login using a cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your cron call you put:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.urlgoeshere.co.uk/index.php cron_event
```

I think it must be:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.urlgoeshere.co.uk/index.php/cron_event
```

Or:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.urlgoeshere.co.uk/cron_event
```

If you removed index.php from your URL.

Comment: so the problem is the login mechanism or the incorrect url  calling?

Comment: I changed the URL which sorted the issue. :)

Comment: Does this still apply, if yes then what's the use of ```$this->input->is_cli_request()```?